# Problem in increasing the distance between labels in contour plot in a TikZ picture

Tags: pgfplots

I am having problem in increasing the distance between the labels in a contour plot in a TikZ picture. I tried a value from `10` to `10000` for the key `contour/label distanc` just to have only one label on each contour level. All I tried didn't give me the result I want. Is there something that I am missing?

Here is the code I used:

```
\documentclass[crop=true,border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis on top,
            title = {$\omega_\phi\left(x, \sigma\right) = \frac{\Gamma}{\pi{R_c}^2}\exp\left[-\frac{\left(x-x_0\right)^2+\left(\sigma-R_0\right)^2}{{R_c}^2}\right]$},
            xmin=2, xmax=3,
            ymin=2, ymax=3,
            view={0}{90},
            xlabel = {$x$},
            ylabel = {$\sigma$},
            ]
            \addplot3[
                    contour gnuplot = {contour label style={
                                nodes={text=black},
                                /pgf/number format/fixed,
                                /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true,
                                /pgf/number format/precision=1,}},
                    samples=2000,
                    contour/draw color={black},
                    contour/label distance=1000,
            ]
            {1/3.1415927/0.25^2*exp(-((x-2.5)^2+(y-2.5)^2)/0.25^2)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I couldn't get `contour/label distance=1000,` to work for my case. The following is the picture of the above code with `samples=2000` and `contour/label distance=1000,`. I would like to have only one label on each contour.

[image]

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 9):

`contour/label distance` is a length and needs some units, e.g. you should write `1000pt` rather than just `1000`.  The default value is `70pt`.  Here are two cruder plots with different values for this parameter:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[crop=true,border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis on top,
        xmin=-1, xmax=1,
        ymin=-1, ymax=1,
        view={0}{90},
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$\sigma$},
        ]
        \addplot3[
                contour gnuplot = {contour label style={
                            nodes={text=black},
                            /pgf/number format/fixed,
                            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true,
                            /pgf/number format/precision=1,}},
                contour/draw color={black},
                contour/label distance=1000pt,
        ]
        {exp(-(x^2+y^2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis on top,
        xmin=-1, xmax=1,
        ymin=-1, ymax=1,
        view={0}{90},
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$\sigma$},
        ]
        \addplot3[
                contour gnuplot = {contour label style={
                            nodes={text=black},
                            /pgf/number format/fixed,
                            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true,
                            /pgf/number format/precision=1,}},
                contour/draw color={black},
                contour/label distance=50pt,
        ]
        {exp(-(x^2+y^2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Adding a `samples` option works, but only up to a certain threshhold.  Here is the case with `samples=100` which is as expected.  If you change to `samples=131` then the label spacing changes, perhaps due to some overflow problem.

`samples=100`

[image: Sample smooth output]

`samples=131`

[image: Sample wrong labelling]

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
\documentclass[crop=true,border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis on top,
        xmin=-1, xmax=1,
        ymin=-1, ymax=1,
        view={0}{90},
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$\sigma$}]
        \addplot3[samples=100,
                contour gnuplot = {contour label style={
                            nodes={text=black},
                            /pgf/number format/fixed,
                            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true,
                            /pgf/number format/precision=1}},
                contour/draw color={black},contour/label distance=1000pt]
        {exp(-(x^2+y^2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis on top,
        xmin=-1, xmax=1,
        ymin=-1, ymax=1,
        view={0}{90},
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$\sigma$}]
        \addplot3[samples=100,
                contour gnuplot = {contour label style={
                            nodes={text=black},
                            /pgf/number format/fixed,
                            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true,
                            /pgf/number format/precision=1}},
                contour/draw color={black},contour/label distance=50pt]
        {exp(-(x^2+y^2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. It works fine when the number of samples are low. There is one problem. Since I want to have a smooth contour line, I used `samples=2000`. Even using `contour/label distance=10000pt` does not produce the contour levels to have only one label. Could you please comment on the sample size? All my packages are updated to their latest version.

Comment: You are right, when the number of samples is high, the label distance option seems to not have the desired effect.  In my example, `samples=130` is fine, `samples=131` causes the labels to be misplaced.  My guess is that this some arthmetic overflow.  Note that `samples=100` gives a fairly smooth plot in my example.

Comment: PS your example compiles without label problems for `samples=250` and is reasonably smooth.  Testing higher values is taking too much time on my machine.